# Orange Outline on Clickable Elements in Android Webview

Tags: javascript, html, css, cordova, android-webview

I am building a Cordova App for Android devices. One thing bothered me a lot: A semi-transparent orange background and an orange outline were displayed every time I tap on a clickable element.

The following screen capture shows this annoying behaviour. On the left hand side, a styled DIV element is being touched; on the right hand side, a DIV element having the same style is in its normal state.

[image: Left hand side: Being touched; Right hand side: Inactive;]

After a bit of research online, including reading a number of questions on StackOverflow, I'm able to remove the orange highlight in the middle using the `-webkit-tap-highlight-color` CSS attribute.

However, the darker orange outline (with rounded corner) remains there. I've also tried the following CSS:

```
*, *:focus, *:active, *:hover{
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    outline: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

Still, the outline appears whenever I touched any clickable elements.

Weird enough, I found the text selection and touch callout are not being blocked as well. Only `-webkit-tap-highlight-color` worked as expected from the above CSS.

## Update

I have tested the app on the following devices:

- [XiaoMi Mi-One](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xiaomi_MI-One)
- [XiaoMi Phone 2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xiaomi_Phone_2)
- [XiaoMi Phone 2S](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xiaomi_Phone_2S)
- [Samsung Galaxy S III](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samsung_Galaxy_S_III)
- [Samsung Galaxy Note II](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samsung_Galaxy_Note_II)

I found that the outline doesn't disappear only on the XiaoMi Phone 2 and 2S. I guess it is because of the default browser on these devices (or more accurately, on the MIUI ROM installed) not being the same one from stock Android.

Still, I'm looking for a way to get around this, if there is any.

Comment: I know this is an old question, but did you ever find a way to remove the outline?